# Facebook avatar image download using Webclient always return 403 status code in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, webclient

I am developing an Asp.net mvc Website. In my website , I am downloading facebook avatar image to my server. I am using web client for it. But when I download it always returns 403 status code.

My Facebook avatar URL is something like this

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14695341_648936665270833_5179578061817683778_n.jpg?oh=ee4f3c5fd796e9b65053451f4e8b4e16&oe=58906D70
```

I download like this

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    public string DownloadFacebookAvatar(string url)
    {
        string path = null;
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {

            string filename = "avatar.jpeg";
            string physicalPath = Path.Combine(dir, filename);
            path = dir + "/" + filename;

            webClient.DownloadFile(url, physicalPath);
        }
        return path;
    }
```

When I download, it is giving me this error.

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Where did you get the image URL from in the first place? You should only use URLs you got from a current API request. (Facebook CDN URLs are to be considered “transient,” and not valid forever.)

Comment: The `oh=ee4f3c5fd796e9b65053451f4e8b4e16&oe=58906D70` part probably session tokens issued by FB security system, which has limited time period. 403 forbidden makes sense for this, since the token may expired when trying to download the image with your code.

Comment: I request the url by accessing in the broswer like this, http://graph.facebook.com/100004635154677/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false . Then I copied the url value and pass it as paramter.